# Two questions regarding exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Question #1:

$$\frac{\frac{x^{2}y^{-3}}{3z^{{2}}} - \frac{z^{-3}y^{-3}}{3x^{2}}}{\frac{x^{-4}y^{2}}{3z^{-2}}}$$

Question #2:

$$(x^{-1} + y^{-1})^{-1}$$

Answer to Question #1:
$$\frac{x^{6}z - x^{2}}{y^{5}z^{5}}$$

Answer to Question #2:
$$\frac{xy}{x + y}$$

These questions are from the book Just in Time Algebra & Trig for Calculus, Section 1.4.

I am not able to reach the final answer for both of these problems, and I could use some help.  And if you can clarify which "laws of exponents" are being used as well, because the second question above seems easy but I can't get the answer.

Thanks.

Comment: to answer your question as to which exponent rules to use, use these:

$x^a = \frac{1}{x^{-a}}$ ;

$x^{-a} = \frac{1}{x^a}$ ;

$x^a \cdot x^b = x^{a+b}$ ;

$(x^a)^b = x^{a \cdot b}$ ;

Answer (score 1):

Hint to your first Question:
Write
$$\frac{x^2}{3z^2y^2}-\frac{1}{3x^2y^3z^3}=\frac{x^4z}{3x^2y^3z^3}-\frac{1}{3x^2y^3z^3}$$
and you will get
$$\frac{(x^4z^2-1)}{3x^2y^3z^3}\cdot \frac{3x^4}{y^2z^2}$$
The result should be $$\frac{x^2 \left(x^4 z-1\right)}{y^5 z^5}$$